# Modelling backspin on an English pool table

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am trying to create a simple animation for a backspin shot. I need to derive a position vector and rotation vector for the ball so that I can input keyframes

[image]

I have just uploaded a test animation to youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UBs8-HECqc
However, this animation looks a bit odd. I have assumed a linear deceleration of rotation which resulted in a quadratic formula for the rotation. I have assumed the translation to be constant which I know is incorrect as the backspin will act to slow the ball down. I don't know how to take this into account mathematically though.

Some googling has yielded these physical constants for an American pool table

[image]

An English pool table has a slightly smaller ball 15/8 of an inch and a napped cloth. Thank you in advance for any help.